# Is there any way to automatically declare a variable with the same type as the function's return type?

Tags: c++

I don't want to declare the return value two times, so maybe there is a more clever way in modern C++ to do this, but I couldn't find any way.

So, instead of this:

```
int calculate() {
    int ret=0;
    return ret;
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
int calculate() {
    decltype(return_type) ret=0;
    return ret;
}
```

It would make it easier to change the return type if needed.

If it's not possible, then why is it not possible?

Comment: `auto calculate()` ?

Comment: or `decltype(auto) calculate()`

Comment: `decltype(calculate()) ret = 0;`?

Comment: @user17732522 I was thinking about the original function (the top one). `decltype(auto)` should be fine there, no?

Comment: The way things are going, one's entire program will probably soon be just `auto ();` :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that would be nice, because I would rather do the automatization in return variable declaration than in the function declaration, but that makes the name of the function and the signature redundant.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Oh sorry, yes decltype's special rule for directly naming variables is also applied in that case. Still, usually `decltype(auto)` is dangerous if you don't want the function to be forwarding references, e.g. `return(ret);` does cause the issue I referred to.

Comment: @ÁdámBakai If the function is a template, another option is to store the return type in a dummy template parameter. It requires somehow guarding against the user passing a custom type though.